# Getting a script error with an angular app on ie

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

My angular app does not work in ie hosted on a basic IIS webserver.

The App works correctly on my local webserver with IE however if i go to the website i get the following errors:

```
SCRIPT5014: Array.prototype.slice: 'this' is not a JavaScript object
```

angular.min.js, line 26 character 36

```
SCRIPT5022: [$sce:iequirks] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.7/$sce/iequirks
```

angular.min.js, line 34 character 426

I'm using the production version of the angular.

I've already looked at the IE guide (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) and here is my markup.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="Results">
    <body>
      ... My Website Code ....

       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
        <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is my app.js file

'use strict';

```
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('Results', [
  'ngRoute',
  'Results.filters',
  'Results.services',
  'Results.directives',
  'Results.controllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

}]);
```

I didn't choose to create the elements, because I don't have to support ie versions earlier than IE 9. So, what am i Missing?

Comment: Fyi: You are using a beta version of angular.  You will get better error messages from angular if you do not use the minified version.

Comment: @Breck421 i switched to the unminified version of angular 2. Then it was clear that it was a compatibility mode problem. I set the meta tag so that it forces it into a non quirks mode.